# I'm trying to add an image to my react native app, after specifying the path the image file is not showing in my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Trying to add an image file in my react project after specifying the path, the image is not displaying on the app. What could be the problem

What could be the problem here, trying to display an image in my react native app.

Comment: Share your code sample to find the issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.